# Use of "or" in "when" of "if" statements

Tags: qgis, sql, if-statement

Can you use "or" in "when" statements?

I have a dataset were I have to insert strings in case of numbers. example

```
field1: 1,2,5,6,10: 
field2:'num','left','pro','con'
```

I want to insert the values of field 2 in the plase of field1 as `1=num, 2=left, 5 and 6=pro, 10=pro`

I have tried with: `CASE When "field1"='5' or "field1"='6' then 'pro' else "field1" END`

I have not found a way to insert more then one variable at the time. Can this be solved a easy way, for example by using or?

Comment: Maybe parentheses are needed? CASE When ("field1"='5' or "field1"='6') then 'pro' else "field1" END

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: im using QGIS 3.22

Comment: Why not all at once? `CASE 
   when "field1"= 1 then 'num'
   when "field1"= 2 then 'left'
   else 'pro'
END` . However: if `field1` is of fieldtype integer, you can't insert text.

Comment: that also work. thx. 

Reposts this answar further down to make it easyer to find.

Answer (score 5):

The IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

The IN operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions.

```
case
    when "field1" IN('5','6') then 'pro' --IN(5, 6) if field1 is numeric
   --more when condition goes here
    else "field1"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not all at once?

```
CASE
   when "field1"= 1 then 'num'
   when "field1"= 2 then 'left'
   else 'pro' 
END
```

However: if field1 is of fieldtype integer, you can't insert text.

*Copy of a [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/420893/use-of-or-in-when-of-if-statements#comment685990_420893) by [@Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel)*